# Slope of normal

Tags: derivatives, solution-verification

Let a curve given by $y=x+\cos(xy) $. Find the slope of normal line at $(0,1) $ point.
My solution:
$$f(x,y) =y-x-\cos(xy)=0$$
$$f'=-f_x/f_y=\dfrac{1-y\sin(xy)}{1+x\sin(xy)}$$ so $f'(0,1)=1$ and slope of normal line must be $-1$.
Is it true? Any mistake? Thanks.

Comment: Look correct to me.